# How can I select all markers and display the list of those markers by drawing a shape on the map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a mobile app using Flutter, and I want that when I draw an arbitrary shape, it will select the markers within that shape and display their information.

I haven't found a solution to that issue. I hope that people can guide me through it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.